# Include of non-modular header when including third party framework in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, include, header-files

I need to expose a method in my header file to accept a parameter of a type that comes from a third party framework. The method stub looks like this:

```
- (void) onComplete:(RETURN_CODE (^)(BOOL isSuccess, NSData* tags))onComplete;
```

RETURN_CODE is a typedef enum in the third party framework, but it's not the typical enum definition. It looks like this:

```
typedef enum {
    RETURN_CODE_DO_SUCCESS = 0,              
    RETURN_CODE_ERR_DISCONNECT = 0xFF01,         
    RETURN_CODE_ERR_CMD_RESPONSE = 0xFF02,
    // continued...
}
```

When I try importing it in my header file, I get the error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module"

I've gotten around this before using protocol and class before, but I'm not sure how to get around this for the RETURN_CODE type. I already have the 'Allow non-modular includes' option set to Yes. Both my framework and the third party framework are included in a bridging header in my swift project.

My framework's structure is such that A.h imports C.h, A.m imports B.h, and B.h imports C.h. I don't think this should be a problem?

Since it's a third party framework that I'm importing, I'm not sure if I can change it's target membership. It's already included in the Link Binary With Libraries list. For lulz, I dragged and dropped it to the Public headers section, but that didn't help.

I tried making a module map file, but that didn't change anything either. I'm not sure if I created it correctly, I just got the same error as before even after removing the bridging header.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Go to header file and change it to public.

[image: Change Header File]

**Option 2:** 
Go to Project > Build Settings > Apple LLVM 9.0 - Language - Modules > All Non-Modular Includes in Framework Modules = YES

[image: Change Build Settings]